# Not sure when to use Distributive Law in specific Proofs question.

Tags: proof-verification, logic, proof-writing, proof-explanation, predicate-logic

I'm currently using "How to Prove It" by Velleman, and I'm stuck on Chapter 2.2 question 6. I found the solution online on how to do it, but I don't understand it.

Here's the question:

```
Show that ∃x(P(x) V Q(x)) equals ∃xP(x) V ∃xQ(x).
```

Here's the answer:

```
¬¬∃x(P(x) V Q(x))=
¬∀x¬(P(x) V Q(x))=
¬∀x(¬P(x) ∧ ¬Q(x))=
¬(∀x¬P(x) ∧ ∀x¬Q(x))= (a)
¬∀x¬P(x) V ¬∀x¬Q(x) (b)
∃x¬¬P(x) ∨ ∃x¬¬Q(x)
∃xP(x) V ∃xQ(x)
```

My problem:

1. Why are we able to use the distributive law here when we couldn't use it 
   to solve the whole question using it in the first place.
2. Here we used the negation law so that changed the middle sign. What I'm 
   wondering is why the ¬ next to the P and Q is not removed, since we're 
   supposed to reverse everything, including the sign too [like in $-[P(x)] = - P(x)]$.

Comment: Presumably distributivity of $\forall$ is an axiom or a previously proven result but not distributivity of $\exists$. You have to derive theorems from the axioms you're given. You don't get to use some theorem that you heard about some other place. (b) is just de Morgan; $P$ and $Q$ aren't involved at all.

Comment: @DerekElkins When you get a question that is phrased like the one above, how do you know which laws/theories to use and which not?

Comment: The book should have told you at some point what the axioms/rules of inference they are using are. Ideally, there would be a clear listing of axioms/rules, but it may have introduced them incrementally. In that case, the theorems you should be able to use are the ones that have been previously proven or assumed as axioms.

Comment: @DerekElkins Alright. You've answered both of my questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is more a comment than an direct answer to your question, but somehow I doubt that most mathematicians would be applying such rules (really theorems of logic) in writing proofs. While such rules may save a few lines of proof, it may be easier to simply apply the more basic rules of logic. Here are the first 5 of 28 lines in my formal proof (in the DC Proof format) to get you started. (Note: Here, '|' is the OR-operator.)

[image]